# how to customize range of xtics in gnuplot histogram?

Tags: gnuplot

I plot a histogram in gnuplot, everything works fine expect I want to have customized xtics: my data contains values from 1 to 200 but most of them are at interval 1 to 10, so I wanna have xtics like from 1 at interval 1 and end at 10 and the rest will be with no xtics. The gnuplot places xtics from 0 to 200 if I write it like this:

`plot \"$histogram\" u 2:xtic(1)  notitle`

and If I write this:

`set xtics 0,1,10
plot \"$histogram\" u 2  notitle`

then gnuplot places "0" xtic to the place of "1" xtic

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't understand what you exactly need. It would help if you could upload an image of your current result.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, note that both your alternatives place data points according to their line number and not the value in the first column of your data file. Given what you want tics to behave like, this may not be what you want. To avoid this, you have to use a `using` instruction like `u 1:2` or `u 1:2:xtic(1)`.

The command `set xtics 0,1,10` explicitly instructs Gnuplot to start tics at 0; if you want tics to start at 1, you need `set xtics 1,1,10`.

Thus, you probably want:

```
set xtics 1,1,10
plot "histogram" u 1:2 notitle
```

However, unless you are more precise about what your datafile looks like and how you want it to be plotted, I cannot be sure.

Comment: If he really plots `with histogram`, then you cannot specify explicit x-positions, but they are implicitely numbered starting at 0, which is probably the main source of the problem.

Comment: @Christoph: But if he plots with `with histogram`, the sentence starting with “The gnuplot places xtics from 0 to 200 if …” would not make much sense. But we don’t know after all.